# Differences between “consult” and “counsel”

Tags: difference

Why are organizations that provide psychological help called “counselling services”, while those that provide legal, medical, or financial services called “consulting services”?

Is “A consults B” equal to “B counsels A”?

Comment: Can equal be a verb?

Comment: Yes, but not if you write “[...]equal to[...]”. Feel free to change it to “Does ‘A consults B’ equal ‘B counsels A’” if you feel that better captures your meaning, it just wasn't correct in its original _in-between_ form.

Comment: Have you tried looking counsel and consult up in a dictionary? What does it say? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Matt, have you tried looking them up? Were you enlightened by any of the dictionaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various forms of *consult* and *counsel* are derived via French from Latin *consulo* (*consulere*, *consului*, *consultum*). This word in itself carries conflicting meanings— [asking for advice, receiving it, reflecting on it](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=consulere&la=la)— and so it should be no surprise that the English derivatives have multiple usages, some of which are antonyms but others which are not.

In particular, the noun forms *counselling* and *consulting* refer to specific professional practices, beyond providing counsel or being consulted. After all, I can profess my fondness for music, but that does not make me a *professor*; I can account for all my golf clubs, but I am not performing *accounting* (or *accountancy*).

*Counselling* (BrE) / *counseling* (AmE) is idiomatically identified with

> [the provision of professional assistance and guidance in *resolving personal or psychological problems*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counselling)

(emphasis added), perhaps because of common association. Similarly, *therapy* on its own will be intrepreted as *psychotherapy* or *psychological therapy*; one specifies *physical therapy* if undergoing an exercise regimen for muscles and joints rather than feelings and relationships.

*Consulting* is

> [the business of giving expert advice to other professionals](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consulting)

The "short" answer to your first question, then, is that *counselling* has become closely identified with advice given to *individuals* (whether alone or in groups) to assist with their emotional problems, whereas *consulting* is sought to address problems in a business or professional practice or process.

These usages color the use of *counsel* and *consult* as verbs. Generically, they mean simply to give advice and to seek advice respectively. To say *she is counselling him* without other context, however, will usually be interpreted as saying she is offering psychological or emotional guidance. And confusingly, especially in American usage, to *consult* can mean to be employed as a consultant— and thus to be giving rather than requesting advice: *He consults for Accenture*; *She consults at the World Bank*.

The noun forms *counsel* and *consultation* (sometimes abbreviated to *consult*) also have specific usages that can overshadow their generic ones. We can also speak of *taking your mother's counsel* or *working in consultation with our partners*. But *counsel*, thanks to television courtroom procedurals, can be taken as *legal counsel*, meaning either your lawyer or to the advice they officially provide. A *consultation* is the time a professional takes to evaluate your case, as when you first meet your lawyer or doctor about a particular issue: *set up an appointment for your consultation*.

---

As to your second question, yes, *[equal](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/equal_17)* can be used as a verb, meaning either to be equal or to make equal. But unless dealing with numerical quantities, I think a native speaker would more likely ask if something *is the same as* another, or whether it *is equivalent to* or *is equal to* as you have done.

Comment: You say "counselling has become closely identified with advice given to individuals (whether alone or in groups) to assist with their emotional problems" but how does it comply with lawyers? Or this sentence from a dictionary "Mrs. Shannon counseled her students on how to get into art school."? It's not about emotional help

Comment: @user1425 I stand by my answer, which specifically refers to "cousenl[l]ing" and not any other form of "counsel." "Mrs. Shannon offered counseling to her students" would absolutely be interpreted as referring to emotional support in the absence of other context.

Comment: So you think that it's about emotional support? "Mrs. Shannon counseled her students on how to get into art school." She didn't give any practical advice? It's weird.

Comment: Do you think this is correct "Could you counsel me on this matter?" What does it mean?